# How use nodemon on VS code

Tags: terminal, nodemon

I've been trying to use nodemon on vs code by changing the scripts section on a Json file to "devStart":"server.js" from "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1" then using git bash to run it by using " $ npm run devStart" and I get this error every time
"npm ERR! missing script: devStart
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     start"
how can i fix this error?

I have tried to download nodemon globally looking at an instructional video here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIbAtxPq5_I but unfortunately after I followed all the steps and restarted VS code it didn't work when I tried to connect it in the terminal to my js file. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `devStart` to "nodemon server.js" instead of just the filename. Your scripts property in package.json should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js"
},
```

Now run using `$ npm run devStart`.